# Should MDB call remove() after using stateless session bean?

Tags: weblogic, ejb, jboss-mdb, stateless-session-bean

Our years-old WebLogic J2EE application has a message-driven bean which makes use of a stateless session bean. The MDB onMessage method gets the home interface of the stateless session bean and calls the home interface's `create()` method to get the actual stateless session bean itself.

The code does not attempt to cache the session bean, just uses it directly:

```
public void onMessage(Message message) 
{
    ...
    MySessionBeanLocal ejbLocal = MySessionBeanLocalHome.create();
    ejbLocal.myMethod();
```

There is no corresponding `remove()` call in the MDB.

My question is:  is it bad not to be calling `remove()` in this case?

I'm fairly sure that one is required to call `remove()` for a state*ful* session bean, but it's less clear to me if the `remove()` call is necessary for state*less*.

We recently made significant performance improvements but suddenly began to run out of stateful session beans under load with this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An invocation of EJB MyMessageDrivenBean(Application: 
MyApplication, EJBComponent: MyApplication.jar) timed out while waiting to get an instance from the free pool.
    at weblogic.ejb20.pool.StatelessSessionPool.waitForBean(StatelessSessionPool.java:229)
    at weblogic.ejb20.pool.StatelessSessionPool.getBean(StatelessSessionPool.java:100)
    at weblogic.ejb20.manager.StatelessManager.preInvoke(StatelessManager.java:140)
    at weblogic.ejb20.internal.BaseEJBLocalObject.preInvoke(BaseEJBLocalObject.java:228)
    at weblogic.ejb20.internal.StatelessEJBLocalObject.preInvoke(StatelessEJBLocalObject.java:53)
    at MyMessageDrivenBean_x56omo_ELOImpl.processMessage(MyMessageDrivenBean_x56omo_ELOImpl.java:28)
    at MyMessageDrivenBean.onMessage(TBMessageListener.java:94)
    at weblogic.ejb20.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:370)
    at weblogic.ejb20.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:262)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:2678)
```

Our MDB pool is set to:

```
<message-driven-descriptor>
<pool>
    <max-beans-in-free-pool>20</max-beans-in-free-pool>
    <initial-beans-in-free-pool>5</initial-beans-in-free-pool>
```

Our stateless session bean pool is set to:

```
<stateless-session-descriptor>
<pool>
     <max-beans-in-free-pool>50</max-beans-in-free-pool>
     <initial-beans-in-free-pool>5</initial-beans-in-free-pool>
```

My question is, is the MDB that calls `create()` on the stateless session bean also responsible for calling the `remove()` for the state*less* session bean as well?  (The application seems to have run for years without calling `remove()`, but I'm wondering if improved throughput has exposed an old bug.)

Answer (score 0):

The `remove()` method would be called anyway after the remote interface object is garbaged.

I think no EJB application should obligate explicitly calling the remove() methods, if that happens, it's probably because the pool is too small. Of course you call always using  for fine-tuning, but this should be an exception, not the rule.